# Changes to keys of service account do not impact running service instance

Tags: jwt, google-cloud-endpoints, service-accounts

Adding or removing of keys for service account not reflected in ESP proxy for REST service

I'm trying to test dynamic updates of keys for a service account. This service account is used for authenticating requests to a REST service. The REST service is behind an ESP instance. Authentication works as expected for keys that were available during start of the service. However, e.g. a key that has been added *after* the service was started cannot be used for authentication.

Restarting the service when keys were added or removed seems not a good solution. Ideally, the ESP proxy would recognize (maybe after a delay), that new keys have been added (or removed).

Comment: I assume you following this [instruction ](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/service-account-authentication) to use service account to authenticate between services.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you following this [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/service-account-authentication)  to use service account to authenticate between services.  If so,you may run into JWKS cache issue.  ESP caches the JWKS for 5 minutes. You can reduce the cache duration by using --jwks_cache_duration_in_s [flag](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/start_esp/start_esp.py#L911)

Answer (score 0):

This was the case: The ESP does cache the keys and therefore the updates to the valid keys take some time. With some patience, it does work.
Curiously, when the setup is run within GKE instead of kube, the changes to the keys seems to propagate much faster, even though the configuration is the same. However, it works as expected.